# JQuery iframe contents cross-domain

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to use jQuery to access the contents of an iframe when the iframe source is on a different domain? I'm not looking to modify the contents, just read in the html when the iframe is finished, so that's why I'm not sure if this falls under the [Same Origin Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe).

ex:

domain : http://www.example-A.com/

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#helper").append("<iframe src='http://www.citizensbank.com' ></iframe>");
        getContents("#helper");
    });
    function getContents(iframeID) {
        if ($(iframeID + " iframe").context.readyState != "complete") {
            setTimeout("getContents('" + iframeID + "');", 200);
        } else {
            alert($(iframeID + " iframe").contents().html());
        }
    }
</script>
<div id="helper"><iframe src="http://www.example-B"></iframe></div>
```

Comment: Yep, this falls under the Same Origin Policy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it is not possible to read the contents of an iframe using javascript if the iframe's src is a different domain from the parent page.